# Is it possible to use Mapbox as background Layer with GWT-OpenLayers?

Tags: gwt, mapbox, openlayers-3, gwt-openlayers

Is it possible to use Mapbox as background Layer  with GWT-OpenLayers? ( http://www.gwt-openlayers.org/ ) ?

If yes, is there some code somewhere ?

Thanks in advance